# Passing '+' At the query-string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, special-characters, query-string

How to pass special characters e.g. '+' or '#' at the query string?

I am calling an MVC action and passing the value "abc+def" as a query string, but while I was debugging I noticed that the passed value is "abc def" (the '+' character was replaced by space!)

This is the code of the action

```
public ActionResult Index(string textSearch)
{
    //...
}
```

And this is the JS line of code that calls the previous action

```
window.location.href = "/Books/Index?textSearch=" + txtBooksFilter.val();
```

The value that I wrote at the text input was "abc+def" but the value that passed to the server is "abd def"
And the url at the browser is: "/Books/Index?textSearch=abc+def"

How to fix this issue??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `encodeURIComponent()` to escape it.